# A prime superscript in LaTeX/MathJax not displayed correctly

Tags: bug, mathjax

I have a (possible bad) habit of sometimes making a prime superscript in LaTeX with a 'hat' character in between, e.g.,  $x^'$ rather than  $x'$.  The LaTeX/MathJax rendering has worked fine either way for more than a year, right up to around yesterday, where I became aware that $x^'$ is not displayed correctly. See e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33713/2451).

1. What causes this problem to emerge now?
2. Was there a recent change to MathJax?
3. Is there a way to fix this problem without having to edit each and every post separately by hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As of Oct. 23rd](http://www.mathjax.org/2012/10/22/news/mathjax-v2-1-now-available/), MathJax 2.1 should be in use. I suspect (but haven't verified) that [bug fixes](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/278) to how primes and superscripts are handled may have caused the change in behavior you're seeing.

A quick search turns up only 7 posts illustrating this problem - I've listed them below:

- [Galilean relativity in projectile motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38983/galilean-relativity-in-projectile-motion)
- [Galilean transformation of wave equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28912/galilean-transformation-of-wave-equation)
- [Condition for circular orbit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33713/condition-for-circular-orbit)
- [Collision problem: Finding the final speed of the collider](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35003/scattering-problem-finding-the-speed-of-the-scatterer-after-collision)
- [Relativistic Doppler effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37833/relativistic-doppler-effect/37848#37848)
- [Calculating two particle position and velocity with each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35573/calculating-two-particle-position-and-velocity-with-each-other/35602#35602)
- [What does $\psi_j(r_i)$ mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38709/what-does-psi-jr-i-mean/38717#38717)

Comment: Great that only 7 Q&A are affected. Note however that this problem also persists in comments, see e.g. one of my comments to [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/28930/2451) answer.

Comment: I found four comments with this pattern, and fixed them.